# Creating a one-dimensional sandpile model in r

Tags: r

I am trying to create a sandpile model in r. It is one dimensional.

The rules are as follows:

1. There are 10 spaces.
2. Pick a random space. Drop a grain of sand.
3. a. If the space has 0 grains of sand, add 1 grain of sand, for a total of 1.
   b. If it has 1 grain of sand, it now has two and the pile collapses. Distribute one of these grains to each neighbour. If the neighbour has 0 grains of sand, add one. If it has two grains of sand, distribute one to each neighbour. Continue until no more spaces have more than 1 grain. The grains fall off the edge at 0 and 11.

Now I wrote some code. Generating the initial state itself was easy of course:

```
sandpile <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

After figuring out square brackets, I managed to randomly drop sand and update the neighbouring coordinates:

```
drop <- sample (1:10, 1)
sandpile[drop] <- sandpile[drop]+1
if(sandpile[drop] > 1) { (sandpile[drop-1] <- sandpile[drop-1]+1)
if(sandpile[drop] > 1 ) { (sandpile[drop+1] <- sandpile[drop+1]+1)
if(sandpile[drop] > 1) {sandpile[drop] <- sandpile[drop]-2
```

But this does not continue a cascade, meaning the if sandpile[drop-1] > 1, sandpile[drop-2] and sandpile[drop] do not update.

So... My question is basically how I can implement the rest of the model, and then record the size of the avalanches (i.e. the amount of sand grains that move each update) for a number of n updates?

Comment: Thanks! Updated it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# 10 spaces
sandpile <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1)

# Pick a random space
drop <- sample (1:10, 1)

# If the space has 0 grains of sand, add 1 grain of sand. 
if(sandpile[drop]==0){
  sandpile[drop] <- 1
  cat("done")
# If it has 1, distribute one to each neighbor and so on 
} else if(sandpile[drop]==1){
  # Left neighbor(s)
    i <- drop-1  
    while(sandpile[i] > 0 & i > 1){
      if(i > 1){i <- i -1 
      } else if (i == 1 & sandpile[i] > 0){
        break # it fell off
      }else if (i == 1 & sandpile[i] == 0){
        sandpile[i] <- 1
        break
      }
    } 
   if(sandpile[i]==0) sandpile[i] <- 1

   # Right neighbor(s)
   i <- drop+1  
   while(sandpile[i] > 0 & i < 10){
     if(i > 1){i <- i +1 
     } else if (i == 10 & sandpile[i] > 0){
       break # it fell off
     }else if (i == 10 & sandpile[i] == 0){
       sandpile[i] <- 1
       break
     }
   } 
   if(sandpile[i]==0) sandpile[i] <- 1
   cat("done")
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! Just one more question... Do you know how I could record the amount of grains of sand that moved per turn?

Comment: @TheCurlyManLives Glad it works! I upvoted your question. I started off with a lot of `if` statements, but it became clear in short order that that was intractable, so I switched to `while`. Regarding the follow up question -- Not offhand, but if you open another question on it then I will work on it in the morning.

Comment: I posted the question now, if you're still interested in looking at it.